# About the value $H_6({RP}^3\times {RP}^3; Z_2)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

By Kunneth formula: $$ H_6(RP^3 \times RP^3; Z_2)= \bigoplus_{i+j=6} H_i(RP^3;Z_2) \otimes H_j(RP^3;Z_2) \oplus \bigoplus_{i+j=5} Tor(H_i(RP^3,Z_2),H_j(RP^3,Z_2)) $$, and $H_i(RP^3; Z_2)=Z_2$, then $ H_6(RP^3 \times RP^3; Z_2)=Z_2\bigoplus Z_2\bigoplus Z_2$, but $ H_6(RP^3 \times RP^3; Z_2)$ should be $Z_2$, right?

Comment: @TedShifrin Tor appears in the Künneth theorem too, for general coefficient rings. But $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field, so all Tors are zero.

Comment: Another fair analysis. Thanks. I'll delete. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the tensor products and Tor over the coefficient ring, not $\mathbb{Z}$. The tensor product is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{Z}_2$, and the Tors are zero, because $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-module (or because $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field).

Comment: Thank you but I feel confused about the "free" here, like $Ext(Z_2,Z_2)=Z_2$, but $Ext(H,G)=0$ if $H$ is free, and $Z_2$ can be seen as a free $Z_2$ module right?

Comment: In general, $\text{Tor}^R_i(A,B) = 0$ if $A$ or $B$ is a free (or projective) $R$-module (for $i \ge 1$). (A similar thing holds for $\text{Ext}$: $\text{Ext}^R_i(A,B) = 0$ if $A$ is free (or projective) or $B$ is injective, although that doesn't appear in this problem.) But any $\mathbb{Z}_2$-module is free, because $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field.

Comment: Do you mean $ Ext(Z_2,Z_2)=Z_2$ in the case of they are not $Z_2$-module?

Comment: Yeah, over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $\text{Ext}^\mathbb{Z}_1(\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2) = \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 0):

All the tor groups are $0$ (since they are over $Z_2$), and the only $i,j$ with $i+j=6$ which involve non-zero homology groups is $(i,j)=(3,3)$, so $H_6(RP^3\times RP^3;Z_2)=Z_2$.

Comment: I feel confused, $Tor(Z_2,Z_2)=Ker(Z_2{\to}^2 Z_2)= Z_2$ right?